# VS2012 heap space issue when compiling a C++ program that runs a Simulink model

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, heap-memory

I have compiled a (pretty big) Simulink model to a dll file (using an ert_shrdlib target) and created a simple c++ snippet (in Visual Studio 2012 Express) that loads the library and steps through the model. When I try to compile the solution into an executable, I get the following compiler error:

```
error C1060: compiler is out of heap space  c:\matlabr2011b_x86\simulink\include\simstruc.h
```

I've tried to search SO as well as google for ways to deal with this, but am yet to find anything that works. I tried to set /Zm to high (2000) and low (256) values, I've tried /Heap with different values, I've tried to turn off parallell compiling, and use a x64 solution platform.

Since the model is something the company has worked on for a long time (and by many people), I don't think I'll be able to do much about that at this point, so I'm hoping there's a way to deal with this in Visual Studio.

---

Edit:

Yes, in my OP I had not set up the 64-bit compiler correctly, but now I have and I still get the same error.

The simstruc.h header from Simulink that is reffered to in the error message includes some really big structs (~400 elements) and I guess they are the root of the issue. I've tried to set the heap to ridicuolus values (like 20000000000) but it still isn't enough. Seriously though, this workstation has 64GB RAM and should be able to compile this bloody header, surely?!

Comment: Use the 64-bit compiler from the vc/bin/amd64 subdirectory.  Pretty murky how to get that done with Express, I doubt it exposes the settings or even has the compiler.  If you work for a company that doesn't believe in providing their employees with decent tooling then you'll want to take a look at [this site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

It wasn't a problem with the heap, it was a couple of lines of code in the included header (from Mathworks) that my compiler couldn't handle. Once I found them and commented them out it compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler may have exceeded the address space limit for 32-bit applications. <s>The compiler itself doesn't seem to have a 64-bit version (no love from Microsoft).</s> A 64-bit version of the compiler can be found in `vc/bin/amd64` directory. You may have to set `PATH` accordingly, or just invoke cl.exe with its full path manually.

Try also some other compiler, such as ICC or GCC or Clang. Possibly a different OS too.

Comment: I think I've managed to set Visual Studio 2012 Express to use a 64-bit compiler now, but it still runs out of heap space. Is it a settings thing?